# Error al ejecutar test

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Tengo un controlador que llamo desde Postman y funciona

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public ResponseEntity<Person> save(
        @RequestBody @Valid PersonRequest request,
        Authentication authentication) {
    try {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(personService.save(request), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Ahora he creado un test e importado H2 en el pom.xml :

```
@DataJpaTest
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
class ClassroomControllerTest {
@Autowired
private PersonService personService ;

@Test
@Order(1)
@Rollback(value = false)
void create() {
    PersonRequest obj = new PersonRequest ();
    obj.setName("Person_1");
    personService.save(obj);

    Assertions.assertThat(obj.getId()).isGreaterThan(0);
}
```

Pero me da este error:

```
Error executing DDL "create table person (id bigint not null, name varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement
```

Comment: No reuses una pregunta para hacer otra, las respuestas dejan de tener sentido. Deberías deshacer los cambios y crear una nueva pregunta si tienes más dudas

Answer (score 0):

Un test unitario sólo testea una clase/componente. Si quieres testear tu Service, debes mockear sus dependencias. Te aconsejo usar [mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) para mockear el repository, por ejemplo.

Si lo que quieres es hacer un test de integración, entonces puedes generar una base de datos en memoria (por ejemplo [h2](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database)) y configurar para los test un *datasource* que haga uso de esta base de datos.

Comment: he actualizado my post usando h2 pero me da otro error